Different tocdepth for PDF
I need my PDF to have a table of content going down to a deeper level than the actual TOC in the file. By adding the command \setcounter{tocdepth}{3} I set the depth of both the actual TOC and the PDF's TOC to the same depth. Can I have two different settings for them?

yes, you can set bookmarkdepth in the hyperref options.

@UlrikeFischer thank you, that was easier than expected ))
